# Simple getValues/setValues function yields #ERROR

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have this script:

```
function copyThis() {
  const sheetName1 = 'A'
  const sheetName2 = 'B'

  sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName1)
  values = sheet1.getRange('BJ8').getValues()
  
  sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName2)
  sheet2.getRange('B12').setValues(values)
}
```

The result is `#ERROR!` in cell `B12` in sheet `B`. Please help.

Note: Cell `BJ8` contains a formula. I want to copy its value to `B12` which already contains a value.

I was expecting it to get the value (a number) in cell `BJ8` from sheet `A` and paste it into cell `B12` in sheet `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your script is passing an Array to a cell. Replace

```
 values = sheet1.getRange('BJ8').getValues()
```

by

```
 values = sheet1.getRange('BJ8').getValue()
```

and

```
 sheet2.getRange('B12').setValues(values)
```

by

```
 sheet2.getRange('B12').setValue(values)
```

The above will pass a number, string, boolean or Date instead of an Array.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Thank you Ruben :) I can hardly believe that "s" at the end of getValues matters :P

Answer (score 0):

This works also:

```
function copyThis() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sh1.getRange("A2").setValues(sh0.getRange("A1").getDisplayValues())
}
```